# Render images sources from parsed array of objects in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jsx

I'm building a react native application which suppose to use some 'meta-data' objects as sources. I'm parsing each object in array and returning a JSX layout for each `item`. The only problem I have is how to provide  sources from images, since I have them stored locally and need to `require("link")` them. My code gives me error:

```
function loadModuleImplementation(moduleId, module) {
  moduleId = "../../../images/icons/photographer/Party.png"
```

My code:

```
class SelectScreen extends Component {
  props:Props;


  Details = [
        {
          "type": "Party",
          "image": "../../../images/icons/photographer/Party.png"
        },
        {
          "type": "Wedding",
          "image": "../../../images/icons/photographer/Wedding.png"
        },
        {
          "type": "Architecture",
          "image": "../../../images/icons/photographer/Arhitecture.png"
        },
        {
          "type": "Christening",
          "image": "../../../images/icons/photographer/Christening.png"
        }
  ];

  render() {
    let renderPhotoTypes = () => {
      let type = [];

      this.Details.map( ( item )=> {
        type.push(
          <View style={styles.imageSelectItem} key={item.type}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              <View>
                <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                  <Image style={styles.image} source={require(item.image)}/>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.type}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </View>
        );
      } );

      return type;
    };

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styleGuide.containerMain}>
        <Text style={styleGuide.heading_1}>
          Select type
        </Text>

        <View style={styles.imageSelectContainer}>
          {renderPhotoTypes()}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>);
  }
}
```

Versions:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.12.0",
    "babel-relay-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "buffer": "^4.6.0",
    "color": "^0.11.1",
    "invariant": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "~15.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.26.1",
    "react-native-button": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-message-bar": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^2.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-relay": "^0.9.0",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-persist": "^3.2.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  }
```

Comment: What version of react native are you using? was it upgraded from a version < 0.14?

Comment: Added package versions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
  Details = [
        {
          type: "Party",
          image: require("../../../images/icons/photographer/Party.png")
        },
        {
          type: "Wedding",
          image: require("../../../images/icons/photographer/Wedding.png")
        },
        {
          type: "Architecture",
          image: require("../../../images/icons/photographer/Arhitecture.png")
        },
        {
          type: "Christening",
          image: require("../../../images/icons/photographer/Christening.png")
        }
  ];

  render() {
    let renderPhotoTypes = () => {
      let type = [];

      this.Details.map( ( item )=> {
        type.push(
          <View style={styles.imageSelectItem} key={item.type}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              <View>
                <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                  <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image}/>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.type}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </View>
        );
      } );

      return type;
    };
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot. 
Need to think how to wrap it for a JSON Schema now.

Comment: It is actually impossible to use dynamically load an image since require calls are statically parsed and bundled. If you use JSON schema, you will have to use uri property for image source. The other workaround is to use javascript objects(just put them in different modules) instead of JSON schema if that works for you.

Comment: Yes, probably `uri` as a source is the way to go in such situation.

Comment: hey, can you please post the solution you found ... thank you