# Not able to render image in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to load a JPG image from my local folder in my react-native application.

The image is stored inside assets folder which I''m trying to render inside Image tag

Here's my JSON object

```
  {
    title: 'Device 2',
    image: '../assets/imgs/device_default.jpg',
    cta: 'View device',
    mac: '1234-xxxx-xxxx-5678'
  },
```

Here's my code for the same

```
<Block flex style={imgContainer}>
   <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={imageStyles} />
</Block>
```

here item contains the props value. I can iterate other values like title and mac

but not able to render the image.

Can anyone help me on this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON`

```
    title: 'Device 2',
    src : require('../assets/imgs/device_default.jpg'),
    cta: 'View device',
    mac: '1234-xxxx-xxxx-5678'
  },
```

`HTML`

```
<Block flex style={imgContainer}>
   <Image source={item.src} style={imageStyles} />
</Block>
```

Got the exact solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841236/render-images-sources-from-parsed-array-of-objects-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

dynamic paths in require are not currently supported.The only allowed way to refer to an image in the bundle is to literally write require('name-of-the-asset') in the source.

you need to add require for image in your json.Check below example

```
  const Profiles=[
      {
      "id" : "1",
      "name" : "Peter Parker",
      "src" : require('../images/user1.png'),
      "age":"70",
    },
    {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "Barack Obama",
    "src" : require('../images/user2.png'),
    "age":"19",
    },
    {
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "Hilary Clinton",
    "src" : require('../images/user3.png'),
    "age":"50",
    }
]
export default Profiles;
```

Comment: i guess this is correct, what Tim has provided is not a workable solution i guess.

Comment: How should I render the src in HTML?? Using <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={imageStyles} />